# How change SQL Server version

Tags: sql-server, version

On my machine is running SQL Server 2016 version (OS - Windows 10).
I had installed SQL Server 2017 on my machine for the testing purpose.
When I execute query "SELECT @@VERSION" I see that the current version of the SQL Server is 2016.

How can I change it to SQL Version 2017?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have 2 instances of sql server running?  Are you running your query against the correct instance?

Comment: I have two instances of the SQL Server on my local machine.

Comment: I had chosen an incorrect one which led to confusion.
Thank you for a help, now everything is fine.